# Stuck in a switch loop

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I've written an assignment to try and count the numbers of each type of vowel in a string.

It compiles fine, but seems to be looping on the switch statement, and I can't see what I've done wrong, despite about an hour of googling.

Please help! =]

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class assignment3b
 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int alpha=0, epsilon=0, india=0, oscar=0, uniform=0, position=0, length;

    String input;

    char letter;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the vowel parse-o-matic");
    System.out.println("\nThis program will count all lower case vowels in whatever you type.");
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the word you'd like to have parsed : ");

        input = scan.next();

        System.out.println("\n\nThe word " + input + " has: "); // reprints the word before stripping spaces

        input = input.replaceAll("\\s+","");                // Removes whitespace so they don't get counted.

    while (position < input.length());
    {
        letter = input.charAt(position);

        switch (letter)
        {
            case 'a':
                alpha = alpha + 1;
                position = position +1;
                break;
            case 'e':
                epsilon = epsilon + 1;
                position = position +1;
                break;
            case 'i':
                india = india + 1;
                position = position +1;
                break;
            case 'o':
                oscar = oscar + 1;
                position = position +1;
                break;
            case 'u':
                uniform = uniform + 1;
                position = position +1;
                break;
            default:
                position++;
                break;  
        }

        System.out.println("a's = " + alpha);
        System.out.println("e's = " + epsilon);
        System.out.println("i's = " + india);
        System.out.println("o's = " + oscar);
        System.out.println("u's = " + uniform);
        System.out.println("\nOther characters = " + (input.length() - alpha -epsilon - india -oscar - uniform));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: your `println`s are all in the {} after the while loop, that could be why...

Comment: Just a side note, to help with my OCD, please use either `position++` or `position = position + 1`, but please don't use both. It makes me cry.

Comment: also, no need to increment position in each case if you are going to increment it anyway. And no need for position at all, you can fast enum on `String.toCharArray`.

Comment: side note: NATO phonetic alphabet, which seemed to inspire your own, uses `alfa` with an f, and `echo` instead of `epsilon`

Comment: `switch` doesn't "loop". it's basically a nice way of expressing a long `if/elseif/elseif/.../else` tree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon

```
while (position < input.length());
                                 ^
```

which is preventing `position` from being incremented

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class assignment3b
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int alpha = 0, epsilon = 0, india = 0, oscar = 0, uniform = 0, position = 0, length;

            String input;

            char letter;

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Welcome to the vowel parse-o-matic");
            System.out.println("\nThis program will count all lower case vowels in whatever you type.");
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter the word you'd like to have parsed : ");

            input = scan.next();

            System.out.println("\n\nThe word " + input + " has: "); // reprints the word before
                                                                    // stripping spaces

            input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // Removes whitespace so they don't get counted.
            int len = input.length();

            while (position < len)

            {
                letter = input.charAt(position);

                switch (letter)
                {
                    case 'a':
                        alpha = alpha + 1;
                        position = position + 1;
                        break;
                    case 'e':
                        epsilon = epsilon + 1;
                        position = position + 1;
                        break;
                    case 'i':
                        india = india + 1;
                        position = position + 1;
                        break;
                    case 'o':
                        oscar = oscar + 1;
                        position = position + 1;
                        break;
                    case 'u':
                        uniform = uniform + 1;
                        position = position + 1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        position++;
                        break;
                }
            }
                System.out.println("a's = " + alpha);
                System.out.println("e's = " + epsilon);
                System.out.println("i's = " + india);
                System.out.println("o's = " + oscar);
                System.out.println("u's = " + uniform);
                System.out.println("\nOther characters = "
                        + (input.length() - alpha - epsilon - india - oscar - uniform));

        }
    }
```

Try this.

As others mentioned ,you had a semi-colon where it didnt belong.
And also I corrected your logic and moved the print statement outside the loop.

Hope this is what your end result as you expected

```
Welcome to the vowel parse-o-matic

This program will count all lower case vowels in whatever you type.

Please enter the word you'd like to have parsed : striker


The word striker has: 
a's = 0
e's = 1
i's = 1
o's = 0
u's = 0

Other characters = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra semi colon where it doesn't belong.

`while (position < input.length());`

This semicolon isn't a syntax error. Its describing a while block with empty loop content. It translates to:

`while (position < input.length()) {}`

So, drop the semi-colon and you're all good.